dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `before_action' for Appuser:Class (NoMethodError)
I follows guide at https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

but catch erorr

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate scaffold brand brand_name:string company_name:string start_year:integer end_year:integer origin_country:string domestic_country:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20240508094154_create_brands.rb
      create    app/models/brand.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/brand_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/brands.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :brands
      invoke  scaffold_controller
      create    app/controllers/brands_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/brands
      create      app/views/brands/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/brands/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/brands/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/brands/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/brands/_form.html.erb
      create      app/views/brands/_brand.html.erb
      invoke    resource_route
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/controllers/brands_controller_test.rb
      create      test/system/brands_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/brands_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      invoke    jbuilder
      create      app/views/brands/index.json.jbuilder
      create      app/views/brands/show.json.jbuilder
      create      app/views/brands/_brand.json.jbuilder

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>
D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.2.3-p157) ("The Eagle of Durango")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 18544
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/brand" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:26 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate

You have 1 pending migration:

db/migrate/20240508094154_create_brands.rb


):

activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:755:in `check_pending_migrations'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:85:in `execute'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in call'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:39:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/broadcast_logger.rb:240:in `method_missing'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/method_override.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:59:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:24:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:58:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:114:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:141:in `call'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:536:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in `block in handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in `handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:464:in `process_client'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:245:in `block in run'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/brands" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:27 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate

You have 1 pending migration:

db/migrate/20240508094154_create_brands.rb


):

activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:755:in `check_pending_migrations'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:85:in `execute'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in call'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:39:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/broadcast_logger.rb:240:in `method_missing'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/method_override.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
activesupport (7.1.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:59:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:24:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:58:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in `call'
rack (3.0.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:114:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:141:in `call'
railties (7.1.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:536:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in `block in handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in `handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:464:in `process_client'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:245:in `block in run'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started POST "/rails/actions" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:28 +0700
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.3ms)  SELECT * FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = ? ORDER BY "ar_internal_metadata"."key" ASC LIMIT 1  [[nil, "environment"]]
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Migrating to CreateBrands (20240508094154)
== 20240508094154 CreateBrands: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:brands)
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (2.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "brands" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "brand_name" varchar, "company_name" varchar, "start_year" integer, "end_year" integer, "origin_country" varchar, "domestic_country" varchar, "created_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0059s
== 20240508094154 CreateBrands: migrated (0.0074s) ============================

  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20240508094154') RETURNING "version"
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  commit transaction
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Started GET "/brands" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:28 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by BrandsController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering brands/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Brand Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands"
  ↳ app/views/brands/index.html.erb:6
  Rendered brands/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 26.0ms | Allocations: 2806)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 148.3ms | Allocations: 36505)
Completed 200 OK in 222ms (Views: 157.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms | Allocations: 44772)


Started GET "/brands/new?locale=en" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:30 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering brands/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered brands/_form.html.erb (Duration: 15.4ms | Allocations: 3170)
  Rendered brands/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 19.9ms | Allocations: 3482)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 27.1ms | Allocations: 4637)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 28.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 18354)


Started GET "/brands/new?locale=en" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:32 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering brands/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered brands/_form.html.erb (Duration: 1.9ms | Allocations: 1447)
  Rendered brands/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.5ms | Allocations: 1553)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 9.1ms | Allocations: 2693)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 10.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2985)


Started POST "/brands?locale=en" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:55 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "brand"=>{"brand_name"=>"Olym Pianus", "company_name"=>"Olym Pianus", "start_year"=>"2015", "end_year"=>"", "origin_country"=>"China", "domestic_country"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Brand", "locale"=>"en"}
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
  Brand Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "brands" ("brand_name", "company_name", "start_year", "end_year", "origin_country", "domestic_country", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [["brand_name", "Olym Pianus"], ["company_name", "Olym Pianus"], ["start_year", 2015], ["end_year", nil], ["origin_country", "China"], ["domestic_country", ""], ["created_at", "2024-05-08 09:42:56.018075"], ["updated_at", "2024-05-08 09:42:56.018075"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/brands/1?locale=en
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms | Allocations: 3213)


Started GET "/brands/1?locale=en" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:56 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#show as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"}
  Brand Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE "brands"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:63:in `set_brand'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering brands/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered brands/_brand.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 282)
  Rendered brands/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.7ms | Allocations: 1383)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.6ms | Allocations: 2519)
Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 13.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 10967)


Started GET "/brands/1/edit?locale=en" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:42:57 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"}
  Brand Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE "brands"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:63:in `set_brand'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering brands/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered brands/_form.html.erb (Duration: 2.6ms | Allocations: 1519)
  Rendered brands/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.9ms | Allocations: 1833)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.5ms | Allocations: 2969)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 13.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 3656)


Started GET "/brands/1.json" for ::1 at 2024-05-08 16:43:26 +0700
Processing by BrandsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Brand Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE "brands"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/brands_controller.rb:63:in `set_brand'
  Rendering brands/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered brands/_brand.json.jbuilder (Duration: 1.4ms | Allocations: 227)
  Rendered brands/show.json.jbuilder (Duration: 11.3ms | Allocations: 510)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 25.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 1363)


- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2024-05-08 16:44:13 +0700 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C
D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails db:seed
bin/rails aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object (NameError)

            "end_year": null,
                        ^^^^
D:/2024_04_25_rails/vyblog/db/seeds.rb:20:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails db:migration
Unrecognized command "db:migration" (Rails::Command::UnrecognizedCommandError)
Did you mean?  db:migrate

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails db:migrate

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate controller Home index
      create  app/controllers/home_controller.rb
       route  get 'home/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/home
      create    app/views/home/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/home_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>bundle add devise
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
Fetching warden 1.2.9
Fetching responders 3.1.1
Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
Installing warden 1.2.9
Installing responders 3.1.1
Fetching devise 4.9.4
Installing devise 4.9.4

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate devise:install
      create  config/initializers/devise.rb
      create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
===============================================================================

Depending on your application's configuration some manual setup may be required:

  1. Ensure you have defined default url options in your environments files. Here
     is an example of default_url_options appropriate for a development environment
     in config/environments/development.rb:

       config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

     In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.

     * Required for all applications. *

  2. Ensure you have defined root_url to *something* in your config/routes.rb.
     For example:

       root to: "home#index"

     * Not required for API-only Applications *

  3. Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
     For example:

       <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
       <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

     * Not required for API-only Applications *

  4. You can copy Devise views (for customization) to your app by running:

       rails g devise:views

     * Not required *

===============================================================================

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails g devise:views
      invoke  Devise::Generators::SharedViewsGenerator
      create    app/views/devise/shared
      create    app/views/devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb
      invoke  form_for
      create    app/views/devise/confirmations
      create    app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/passwords
      create    app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/registrations
      create    app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/sessions
      create    app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/unlocks
      create    app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/devise/mailer
      create    app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/mailer/email_changed.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/mailer/password_change.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
      create    app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate devise MODEL
Rails cannot recover the underscored form from its camelcase form 'MODEL'.
Please use an underscored name instead, either 'model' or 'mode_l'.
Or setup custom inflection rules for this noun before running the generator in config/initializers/inflections.rb.

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate devise appuser
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20240508104243_devise_create_appusers.rb
      create    app/models/appuser.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/appuser_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/appusers.yml
      insert    app/models/appuser.rb
       route  devise_for :appusers

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails db:migrate
== 20240508104243 DeviseCreateAppusers: migrating =============================
-- create_table(:appusers)
   -> 0.0023s
-- add_index(:appusers, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0009s
-- add_index(:appusers, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0007s
== 20240508104243 DeviseCreateAppusers: migrated (0.0055s) ====================


D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>rails generate devise:views
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `before_action' for Appuser:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  before_commit
        from D:/2024_04_25_rails/vyblog/app/models/appuser.rb:7:in `<class:Appuser>'
        from D:/2024_04_25_rails/vyblog/app/models/appuser.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:290:in `const_get'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:290:in `constantize'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:74:in `constantize'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/devise-4.9.4/lib/devise.rb:327:in `get'
...

D:\2024_04_25_rails\vyblog>


class Appuser < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

    before_action :authenticate_user!
end

How to fix it?
rails generate controller Home index

bundle add devise
rails g devise:views

rails generate devise appuser


Controller != model

My source code https://github.com/donhuvy/rails7_shop

You should add this line to controller, not to model

In Rails action means the method that is dispatched by the router on your contoller when it matches a request to a route. Thus all the *_action callbacks are controller callbacks.
You should add this callback to your ApplicationController so that all actions authenticate by default:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_appuser!
end

Being secure by default prevents you from accidentially creating security holes in your app simply by omission.
Use skip_before_action :authenticate_appuser! to opt out of authentication on the actions that should be publically available.

How to ignore few pages? for example: Home page. I need show about, basic information for user. Now all pages (overall of web-app) require log in :(

skip_before_action :authenticate_appuser!, only: [:home, ...]. All the callbacks and skip accept only:, except:, if: and unless: options that can be used to control when they fire.

Move before_action :authenticate_appuser! (not before_action :authenticate_user! , because entity user has been customized ) to ApplicationController file
since before_action is Controller related method and not Model related.
Example, file C:\GitHub\rails7_shop\app\controllers\products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
    before_action :authenticate_appuser!
    # GET /products or /products.json
    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    # GET /products/1 or /products/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /products/new
    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    # GET /products/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /products or /products.json
    def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @product.save
                format.html { redirect_to product_url(@product), notice: "Product was successfully created." }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
            else
                format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /products/1 or /products/1.json
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @product.update(product_params)
                format.html { redirect_to product_url(@product), notice: "Product was successfully updated." }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
            else
                format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /products/1 or /products/1.json
    def destroy
        @product.destroy!

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: "Product was successfully destroyed." }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :product_type, :size_width, :size_height, :size_length, :unit_of_size, :manufactured_date, :experied_date, :brand_id, :color, :sku)
    end
end

Result: When access http://127.0.0.1:3000/products , will see Login screen.
